# Spring Boot and Google SQL

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-sql

I am using springboot and this guide https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory. This guide help me to generate my jdbc url. I used this jdbc url on my spring boot app but it always bring the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
>   com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]   ... 21 common frames
>   omitted

Please help me thanks all

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWb1K.png)

Comment: You probably need to show your configuration so that the very least, it can be checked for typos, etc. Also, if you use the H2 database, does it work? That's probably the quickest sanity check against your issue being related to the Google stuff.

Comment: @Gregg i have added my application.properties to my question. Check it please

Comment: It would be easier if you just copy and pasted it instead of using a screenshot. That said, the credentials are empty. Is that because a) you're connection doesn't require credentials, b) you forgot them or c) you removed then before posting the screenshot for security purposes?

Comment: @Gregg i am newbie here. I dont know how to use the block code for it sorry.  Yeah i remove my user and password not forgot it.

Comment: Okay, so step 1 is to use H2 and modify your datasource accordingly to make sure it is indeed a Google connection issue, because the error you posted doesn't contain anything useful to determine the root cause. You'll have `compile("com.h2database:h2")` as a dependency and then if you remove all datasource config in your properties file, Spring Boot should just use some sensible defaults and start right up.

Comment: @Gregg i already used MYSQL workbench to connect to my DB in Google. Because it support to connect to IP address so i can connect successfully. Sorry i have never used h2database, hard to follow your guide

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately, I won't be able to help much. Stackoverflow isn't great for ongoing discussions and step by step guides. Nothing you've provided in your question would indicate the error to me. Sorry.

Comment: @Gregg thanks so much for helping. I really dont know why i can't connect.

Comment: Hi How you solved the issue. I am having same when deployed over GAE local build connects fine